# Joining Two Tables, Getting Sum from multiple part numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, sum

First, I'm trying to get a sum for the joined tables. I can join the tables and narrow down the part but there are 2 lines. I know this requires an embedded query but scratching my head on putting it together. This joins the two tables to show the quantity for part number "AC011507NANA". What I'm trying to do is there the total qty_ordered which is this case show 1 and 2 but I need the sum of 3 as there are other parts with much larger counts. In addition, there are about 100 part numbers. Is there a way to display insert all the part numbers here or is it only one by one?

```
SELECT oeordlin_sql.item_no, oeordlin_sql.qty_ordered, oeordlin_sql.ord_no, oeordlin_sql.item_no, oeordhdr_sql.ord_type, oeordhdr_sql.status, oeordhdr_sql.ord_type
FROM oeordlin_sql
INNER JOIN oeordhdr_sql ON oeordlin_sql.ord_no=oeordhdr_sql.ord_no
WHERE oeordhdr_sql.ord_type != 'Q' AND oeordhdr_sql.status != 'L'
AND item_no = 'AC011507NANA';
```

[image]

With David's help I got the proper display. However, I have over 100 part numbers. As mentioned above, is there a way to look up all of them and have the list of items? If not, I'll just go one by one with what I have here.

[image: Item Totals]

Comment: 1) Please post your expected results, in table format 2) SQL is a generic language, and syntax can vary by vendor.  Which dbms *and* version are you using? From the screen shot I'm assuming SQL Server?

Comment: Using SQL Server and looking to have the item number of AC011507NANA and the total quantity of  3

Comment: Clarify via edits, not comments. PS [mre] [ask] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost all the job done, all you need to implement is a sum() and group by.

```
SELECT oeordlin_sql.item_no, sum(oeordlin_sql.qty_ordered) as total
FROM oeordlin_sql
INNER JOIN oeordhdr_sql ON oeordlin_sql.ord_no=oeordhdr_sql.ord_no
WHERE oeordhdr_sql.ord_type != 'Q' AND oeordhdr_sql.status != 'L'
AND item_no = 'AC011507NANA'
GROUP BY oeordlin_sql.item_no;
```

This will return the item_no and the total of the qty_ordered.
Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Hi David Valladares I see I couldn't add all those columns and that, plus the group by was the issue. Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to look up all the item numbers in one fell swoop? I have over 100 to look up? Thanks!

Comment: While perfectly valid if *all* you want is a sum(), this won't work if you want to return other columns too. To clear up the confusion, could you please update your question with the *exact* results you expect?

Comment: That's kinda almost done as well, in your query the only think that is stopping from looking up all of the item_no is `AND item_no = 'AC011507NANA'` so if you remove that part you should see all of the item_no with their total. A plus, if you want them order by id just add after group by... `order by item_no asc`

Comment: I updated the question with an additional photo of what the answer gave me and what I need. I don't need the other columns but just wanted to make sure I was pulling the right data by seeing them initially.

Comment: Okay thanks David. That does pull up the list but it's not to get all of them, just 113 and  shows 396. Trying to figure out the filter.

Comment: Then if you want to limit them to 113 just at the beginning of your script right after the select just add TOP(113) like this `SELECT TOP(113) ....` this is for SQL SERVER

Comment: Hi thanks, I figured it out using "in" because it's not the top or anything as general but specific to certain numbers. I'll just get them all in there.

such as:

SELECT oeordlin_sql.item_no, sum(oeordlin_sql.qty_ordered) as total
FROM oeordlin_sql
INNER JOIN oeordhdr_sql ON oeordlin_sql.ord_no=oeordhdr_sql.ord_no
WHERE oeordhdr_sql.ord_type != 'Q' AND oeordhdr_sql.status != 'L'
AND item_no in ('AC01150299NA', 'AC011507NANA')
GROUP BY oeordlin_sql.item_no;

Comment: OH ok then if is specific number yep, `in` is the way to go. Glad to help